# Proving squared eigenvalue property

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to prove this property of two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ in which $B$ is invertible:

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $B^{-2} A^2 B^2$.

I've identified that $A\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$, then I imagine the next step could be to multiply by $A$ to get an $A^2$ term in there:

$A^2\vec{v} = A\lambda\vec{v}$

After this I thought of multiplying by $B^{-2}$ to get it to more closely resemble the original statement which gave:

$B^{-2}A^2\vec{v} = B^{-2}A\lambda\vec{v}$

After this I am stuck as to what to do next, or if this was even a good approach at all. Just trying to get something that resembles the original proof statement but getting stuck. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You're pretty close. First note that $\lambda$ commutes with the matrices (since it's a scalar), so you can pull it out front. Also, you will want to find a vector $w$ such that $B^{-2}A^2B^2w = B^{-2}A^2v$, and then you can emply your idea from there. Can you think of such a $w$?